# Python opens a file twice even after seting up close_fds=True in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am using close_fds=True in subprocess.Popen but still its opening the file twice. I searched a lot but I am not able to find a solution for this.

I want to open a file and take a screenshot of it.

```
 import os
    import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
    import subprocess as sp
    import time

    def imagegrabber(x=0):
        if(x==1 and __name__ == '__main__'):
            # part of the screen
            im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(50,70,500,500))
            im.show()

        # to file
            ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')
        return;

    def Dashboard(x=0):
        if(x==1):
            mcr = "D:/MCR/test.pbix"
            path = r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe'
            sp.Popen([path,mcr],close_fds=True)
            time.sleep(10)
            imagegrabber(1)
        return;

    Dashboard(1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're seeing that makes you say that it is opening the file twice?

Comment: The power BI is opening and after few seconds a pop up box appears saying "D:/MCR/test.pbix can't be opened as it is already opened".

Comment: Silly question, but do you have that file open in an editor or something while you're trying to run this?

Comment: No. The file gets opened by the python script only and after that I am getting this message. I tried running the code after restarting my system also.

Comment: Its solved. I had to add if( __name__ == '__main__') condition in Dashboard only

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add if(**name** == '**main**') in Dashboard function and not in imagegrabber function. Rest everything is fine.